# Dependency inject variable model

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, dependencies

I have a bunch of repositories that `extends` `abstract BaseRepository`,

How could I have the repositories use the baseRepository's code (`Model::find($id);`) with their own model? I've tried using `self::setModel(new Model)` but when I call `find()` I get an error saying `model` is not an `object`

How I've got it now:
**BaseRepository**

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace App\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
/**
 * Description of BaseRepository
 *
 * @author Jordy
 */
abstract class BaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface {
  protected $model;

  function getModel() {
    return $this->model;
  }

  function setModel($model) {
    $this->model = $model;
    return $this;
  }


  function findBy($prop, $value) {
    return $this->model->where($prop, $value)->get();
  }

  function findById($id) {
    return $this->model->find($id);
  }

  function getAll() {
    return $this->model->all();
  }

  function insertIntoDatabase($data){
    $this->model->create($data);
    return $this;
  }


}
```

**SurveyRepository**

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\MbSurvey as Survey;

/**
 * Description of SurveyRepository
 *
 * @author Jordy
 */
class SurveyRepository extends BaseRepository implements RepositoryInterface {

function __construct() {
    $this->setModel(new Survey);
  }

}
```

This works, but I'd like to do it with a singleton rather than having to do `new repo()` and then `$repo->findById()`

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your BaseRepository. Please add some code.

Comment: You can use `constructor` injection in each child repository.

Comment: I'll update the question with additional info